# Problems with identifying seasonality using decompose

Tags: r, time-series, decomposition

I'm trying to figure out if my hourly time series has a deterministic component or not. So I used decomposition to do so.

```
additive.decomposition<-decompose(ts_data,type=c("additive"))
plot(additive.decomposition)
```

I obtained the following plots: [image: hourly]

To my knowledge, this clearly shows no trend whatsoever. But I'm confused about the seasonal component. Why is it showing up like that?

I aggregated it and made it daily and obtained the following: [image: daily]
I'm really not sure what to make of it.

I tried aggregating the daily data to weekly and plotted it again to obtain the following:
[image: weekly]

So I'm confused, the seasonal component looks way too perfect for it to be considered real. I've read somewhere that even if your time series doesn't admit a seasonal component sometimes a byproduct of using decompose is that it adds seasonality when plotting. Idk if this is right or not.

My concern is, is that real seasonality and if so how can I prove or disprove it.